# Cross compilation of C++ program which includes Opencv4　for OpenWRT

Tags: c++, opencv, openwrt

use g++ is ok, when use mipsel-openwrt-linux-g++ error log

[test@test-pc src]$ mipsel-openwrt-linux-g++ -g -Wall -o HelloWorld  HelloWorld.cpp `pkg-config opencv4 --cflags --libs`

/home/test/openwrt/staging_dir/toolchain-mipsel_24kc_gcc-8.4.0_musl/lib/gcc/mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/8.4.0/../../../../mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_gapi
/home/test/openwrt/staging_dir/toolchain-mipsel_24kc_gcc-8.4.0_musl/lib/gcc/mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/8.4.0/../../../../mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_stitching
/home/test/openwrt/staging_dir/toolchain-mipsel_24kc_gcc-8.4.0_musl/lib/gcc/mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/8.4.0/../../../../mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_alphamat
/home/test/openwrt/staging_dir/toolchain-mipsel_24kc_gcc-8.4.0_musl/lib/gcc/mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/8.4.0/../../../../mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_aruco
/home/test/openwrt/staging_dir/toolchain-mipsel_24kc_gcc-8.4.0_musl/lib/gcc/mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/8.4.0/../../../../mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_bgsegm
/home/test/openwrt/staging_dir/toolchain-mipsel_24kc_gcc-8.4.0_musl/lib/gcc/mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/8.4.0/../../../../mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_bioinspired
/home/test/openwrt/staging_dir/toolchain-mipsel_24kc_gcc-8.4.0_musl/lib/gcc/mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/8.4.0/../../../../mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_ccalib
/home/test/openwrt/staging_dir/toolchain-mipsel_24kc_gcc-8.4.0_musl/lib/gcc/mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/8.4.0/../../../../mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_cvv
/home/test/openwrt/staging_dir/toolchain-mipsel_24kc_gcc-8.4.0_musl/lib/gcc/mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/8.4.0/../../../../mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_dnn_objdetect
/home/test/openwrt/staging_dir/toolchain-mipsel_24kc_gcc-8.4.0_musl/lib/gcc/mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/8.4.0/../../../../mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_dnn_superres
/home/test/openwrt/staging_dir/toolchain-mipsel_24kc_gcc-8.4.0_musl/lib/gcc/mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/8.4.0/../../../../mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_dpm
/home/test/openwrt/staging_dir/toolchain-mipsel_24kc_gcc-8.4.0_musl/lib/gcc/mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/8.4.0/../../../../mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_highgui
/home/test/openwrt/staging_dir/toolchain-mipsel_24kc_gcc-8.4.0_musl/lib/gcc/mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/8.4.0/../../../../mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_face
/home/test/openwrt/staging_dir/toolchain-mipsel_24kc_gcc-8.4.0_musl/lib/gcc/mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/8.4.0/../../../../mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_freetype
/home/test/openwrt/staging_dir/toolchain-mipsel_24kc_gcc-8.4.0_musl/lib/gcc/mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/8.4.0/../../../../mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_fuzzy
/home/test/openwrt/staging_dir/toolchain-mipsel_24kc_gcc-8.4.0_musl/lib/gcc/mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/8.4.0/../../../../mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_hdf
/home/test/openwrt/staging_dir/toolchain-mipsel_24kc_gcc-8.4.0_musl/lib/gcc/mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/8.4.0/../../../../mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_hfs
/home/test/openwrt/staging_dir/toolchain-mipsel_24kc_gcc-8.4.0_musl/lib/gcc/mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/8.4.0/../../../../mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_img_hash
/home/test/openwrt/staging_dir/toolchain-mipsel_24kc_gcc-8.4.0_musl/lib/gcc/mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/8.4.0/../../../../mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_intensity_transform
/home/test/openwrt/staging_dir/toolchain-mipsel_24kc_gcc-8.4.0_musl/lib/gcc/mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/8.4.0/../../../../mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_line_descriptor
/home/test/openwrt/staging_dir/toolchain-mipsel_24kc_gcc-8.4.0_musl/lib/gcc/mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/8.4.0/../../../../mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_mcc
/home/test/openwrt/staging_dir/toolchain-mipsel_24kc_gcc-8.4.0_musl/lib/gcc/mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/8.4.0/../../../../mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_quality
/home/test/openwrt/staging_dir/toolchain-mipsel_24kc_gcc-8.4.0_musl/lib/gcc/mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/8.4.0/../../../../mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_rapid
/home/test/openwrt/staging_dir/toolchain-mipsel_24kc_gcc-8.4.0_musl/lib/gcc/mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/8.4.0/../../../../mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_reg
/home/test/openwrt/staging_dir/toolchain-mipsel_24kc_gcc-8.4.0_musl/lib/gcc/mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/8.4.0/../../../../mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_rgbd
/home/test/openwrt/staging_dir/toolchain-mipsel_24kc_gcc-8.4.0_musl/lib/gcc/mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/8.4.0/../../../../mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_saliency
/home/test/openwrt/staging_dir/toolchain-mipsel_24kc_gcc-8.4.0_musl/lib/gcc/mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/8.4.0/../../../../mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_stereo
/home/test/openwrt/staging_dir/toolchain-mipsel_24kc_gcc-8.4.0_musl/lib/gcc/mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/8.4.0/../../../../mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_structured_light
/home/test/openwrt/staging_dir/toolchain-mipsel_24kc_gcc-8.4.0_musl/lib/gcc/mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/8.4.0/../../../../mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_phase_unwrapping
/home/test/openwrt/staging_dir/toolchain-mipsel_24kc_gcc-8.4.0_musl/lib/gcc/mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/8.4.0/../../../../mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_superres
/home/test/openwrt/staging_dir/toolchain-mipsel_24kc_gcc-8.4.0_musl/lib/gcc/mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/8.4.0/../../../../mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_optflow
/home/test/openwrt/staging_dir/toolchain-mipsel_24kc_gcc-8.4.0_musl/lib/gcc/mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/8.4.0/../../../../mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_surface_matching
/home/test/openwrt/staging_dir/toolchain-mipsel_24kc_gcc-8.4.0_musl/lib/gcc/mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/8.4.0/../../../../mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_tracking
/home/test/openwrt/staging_dir/toolchain-mipsel_24kc_gcc-8.4.0_musl/lib/gcc/mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/8.4.0/../../../../mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_datasets
/home/test/openwrt/staging_dir/toolchain-mipsel_24kc_gcc-8.4.0_musl/lib/gcc/mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/8.4.0/../../../../mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_text
/home/test/openwrt/staging_dir/toolchain-mipsel_24kc_gcc-8.4.0_musl/lib/gcc/mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/8.4.0/../../../../mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_dnn
/home/test/openwrt/staging_dir/toolchain-mipsel_24kc_gcc-8.4.0_musl/lib/gcc/mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/8.4.0/../../../../mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_plot
/home/test/openwrt/staging_dir/toolchain-mipsel_24kc_gcc-8.4.0_musl/lib/gcc/mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/8.4.0/../../../../mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_videostab
/home/test/openwrt/staging_dir/toolchain-mipsel_24kc_gcc-8.4.0_musl/lib/gcc/mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/8.4.0/../../../../mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_videoio
/home/test/openwrt/staging_dir/toolchain-mipsel_24kc_gcc-8.4.0_musl/lib/gcc/mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/8.4.0/../../../../mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_viz
/home/test/openwrt/staging_dir/toolchain-mipsel_24kc_gcc-8.4.0_musl/lib/gcc/mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/8.4.0/../../../../mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_xfeatures2d
/home/test/openwrt/staging_dir/toolchain-mipsel_24kc_gcc-8.4.0_musl/lib/gcc/mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/8.4.0/../../../../mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_shape
/home/test/openwrt/staging_dir/toolchain-mipsel_24kc_gcc-8.4.0_musl/lib/gcc/mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/8.4.0/../../../../mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_ml
/home/test/openwrt/staging_dir/toolchain-mipsel_24kc_gcc-8.4.0_musl/lib/gcc/mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/8.4.0/../../../../mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_ximgproc
/home/test/openwrt/staging_dir/toolchain-mipsel_24kc_gcc-8.4.0_musl/lib/gcc/mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/8.4.0/../../../../mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_video
/home/test/openwrt/staging_dir/toolchain-mipsel_24kc_gcc-8.4.0_musl/lib/gcc/mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/8.4.0/../../../../mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_xobjdetect
/home/test/openwrt/staging_dir/toolchain-mipsel_24kc_gcc-8.4.0_musl/lib/gcc/mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/8.4.0/../../../../mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_objdetect
/home/test/openwrt/staging_dir/toolchain-mipsel_24kc_gcc-8.4.0_musl/lib/gcc/mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/8.4.0/../../../../mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_calib3d
/home/test/openwrt/staging_dir/toolchain-mipsel_24kc_gcc-8.4.0_musl/lib/gcc/mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/8.4.0/../../../../mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_imgcodecs
/home/test/openwrt/staging_dir/toolchain-mipsel_24kc_gcc-8.4.0_musl/lib/gcc/mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/8.4.0/../../../../mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_features2d
/home/test/openwrt/staging_dir/toolchain-mipsel_24kc_gcc-8.4.0_musl/lib/gcc/mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/8.4.0/../../../../mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_flann
/home/test/openwrt/staging_dir/toolchain-mipsel_24kc_gcc-8.4.0_musl/lib/gcc/mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/8.4.0/../../../../mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/bin/ld: cannot fmipsel-openwrt-linux-g++ -g -Wall -o HelloWorld  HelloWorld.cpp `pkg-config opencv4 --cflags --libs`
/home/test/openwrt/staging_dir/toolchain-mipsel_24kc_gcc-8.4.0_musl/lib/gcc/mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/8.4.0/../../../../mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_gapi
/home/test/openwrt/staging_dir/toolchain-mipsel_24kc_gcc-8.4.0_musl/lib/gcc/mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/8.4.0/../../../../mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_stitching
/home/test/openwrt/staging_dir/toolchain-mipsel_24kc_gcc-8.4.0_musl/lib/gcc/mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/8.4.0/../../../../mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_alphamat
/home/test/openwrt/staging_dir/toolchain-mipsel_24kc_gcc-8.4.0_musl/lib/gcc/mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/8.4.0/../../../../mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_aruco
/home/test/openwrt/staging_dir/toolchain-mipsel_24kc_gcc-8.4.0_musl/lib/gcc/mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/8.4.0/../../../../mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_bgsegm
/home/test/openwrt/staging_dir/toolchain-mipsel_24kc_gcc-8.4.0_musl/lib/gcc/mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/8.4.0/../../../../mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_bioinspired
/home/test/openwrt/staging_dir/toolchain-mipsel_24kc_gcc-8.4.0_musl/lib/gcc/mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/8.4.0/../../../../mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_ccalib
/home/test/openwrt/staging_dir/toolchain-mipsel_24kc_gcc-8.4.0_musl/lib/gcc/mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/8.4.0/../../../../mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_cvv
/home/test/openwrt/staging_dir/toolchain-mipsel_24kc_gcc-8.4.0_musl/lib/gcc/mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/8.4.0/../../../../mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_dnn_objdetect
/home/test/openwrt/staging_dir/toolchain-mipsel_24kc_gcc-8.4.0_musl/lib/gcc/mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/8.4.0/../../../../mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_dnn_superres
/home/test/openwrt/staging_dir/toolchain-mipsel_24kc_gcc-8.4.0_musl/lib/gcc/mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/8.4.0/../../../../mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_dpm
/home/test/openwrt/staging_dir/toolchain-mipsel_24kc_gcc-8.4.0_musl/lib/gcc/mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/8.4.0/../../../../mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_highgui
/home/test/openwrt/staging_dir/toolchain-mipsel_24kc_gcc-8.4.0_musl/lib/gcc/mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/8.4.0/../../../../mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_face
/home/test/openwrt/staging_dir/toolchain-mipsel_24kc_gcc-8.4.0_musl/lib/gcc/mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/8.4.0/../../../../mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_freetype
/home/test/openwrt/staging_dir/toolchain-mipsel_24kc_gcc-8.4.0_musl/lib/gcc/mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/8.4.0/../../../../mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_fuzzy
/home/test/openwrt/staging_dir/toolchain-mipsel_24kc_gcc-8.4.0_musl/lib/gcc/mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/8.4.0/../../../../mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_hdf
/home/test/openwrt/staging_dir/toolchain-mipsel_24kc_gcc-8.4.0_musl/lib/gcc/mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/8.4.0/../../../../mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_hfs
/home/test/openwrt/staging_dir/toolchain-mipsel_24kc_gcc-8.4.0_musl/lib/gcc/mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/8.4.0/../../../../mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_img_hash
/home/test/openwrt/staging_dir/toolchain-mipsel_24kc_gcc-8.4.0_musl/lib/gcc/mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/8.4.0/../../../../mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_intensity_transform
/home/test/openwrt/staging_dir/toolchain-mipsel_24kc_gcc-8.4.0_musl/lib/gcc/mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/8.4.0/../../../../mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_line_descriptor
/home/test/openwrt/staging_dir/toolchain-mipsel_24kc_gcc-8.4.0_musl/lib/gcc/mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/8.4.0/../../../../mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_mcc
/home/test/openwrt/staging_dir/toolchain-mipsel_24kc_gcc-8.4.0_musl/lib/gcc/mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/8.4.0/../../../../mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_quality
/home/test/openwrt/staging_dir/toolchain-mipsel_24kc_gcc-8.4.0_musl/lib/gcc/mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/8.4.0/../../../../mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_rapid
/home/test/openwrt/staging_dir/toolchain-mipsel_24kc_gcc-8.4.0_musl/lib/gcc/mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/8.4.0/../../../../mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_reg
/home/test/openwrt/staging_dir/toolchain-mipsel_24kc_gcc-8.4.0_musl/lib/gcc/mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/8.4.0/../../../../mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_rgbd
/home/test/openwrt/staging_dir/toolchain-mipsel_24kc_gcc-8.4.0_musl/lib/gcc/mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/8.4.0/../../../../mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_saliency
/home/test/openwrt/staging_dir/toolchain-mipsel_24kc_gcc-8.4.0_musl/lib/gcc/mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/8.4.0/../../../../mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_stereo
/home/test/openwrt/staging_dir/toolchain-mipsel_24kc_gcc-8.4.0_musl/lib/gcc/mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/8.4.0/../../../../mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_structured_light
/home/test/openwrt/staging_dir/toolchain-mipsel_24kc_gcc-8.4.0_musl/lib/gcc/mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/8.4.0/../../../../mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_phase_unwrapping
/home/test/openwrt/staging_dir/toolchain-mipsel_24kc_gcc-8.4.0_musl/lib/gcc/mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/8.4.0/../../../../mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_superres
/home/test/openwrt/staging_dir/toolchain-mipsel_24kc_gcc-8.4.0_musl/lib/gcc/mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/8.4.0/../../../../mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_optflow
/home/test/openwrt/staging_dir/toolchain-mipsel_24kc_gcc-8.4.0_musl/lib/gcc/mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/8.4.0/../../../../mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_surface_matching
/home/test/openwrt/staging_dir/toolchain-mipsel_24kc_gcc-8.4.0_musl/lib/gcc/mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/8.4.0/../../../../mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_tracking
/home/test/openwrt/staging_dir/toolchain-mipsel_24kc_gcc-8.4.0_musl/lib/gcc/mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/8.4.0/../../../../mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_datasets
/home/test/openwrt/staging_dir/toolchain-mipsel_24kc_gcc-8.4.0_musl/lib/gcc/mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/8.4.0/../../../../mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_text
/home/test/openwrt/staging_dir/toolchain-mipsel_24kc_gcc-8.4.0_musl/lib/gcc/mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/8.4.0/../../../../mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_dnn
/home/test/openwrt/staging_dir/toolchain-mipsel_24kc_gcc-8.4.0_musl/lib/gcc/mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/8.4.0/../../../../mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_plot
/home/test/openwrt/staging_dir/toolchain-mipsel_24kc_gcc-8.4.0_musl/lib/gcc/mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/8.4.0/../../../../mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_videostab
/home/test/openwrt/staging_dir/toolchain-mipsel_24kc_gcc-8.4.0_musl/lib/gcc/mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/8.4.0/../../../../mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_videoio
/home/test/openwrt/staging_dir/toolchain-mipsel_24kc_gcc-8.4.0_musl/lib/gcc/mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/8.4.0/../../../../mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_viz
/home/test/openwrt/staging_dir/toolchain-mipsel_24kc_gcc-8.4.0_musl/lib/gcc/mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/8.4.0/../../../../mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_xfeatures2d
/home/test/openwrt/staging_dir/toolchain-mipsel_24kc_gcc-8.4.0_musl/lib/gcc/mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/8.4.0/../../../../mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_shape
/home/test/openwrt/staging_dir/toolchain-mipsel_24kc_gcc-8.4.0_musl/lib/gcc/mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/8.4.0/../../../../mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_ml
/home/test/openwrt/staging_dir/toolchain-mipsel_24kc_gcc-8.4.0_musl/lib/gcc/mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/8.4.0/../../../../mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_ximgproc
/home/test/openwrt/staging_dir/toolchain-mipsel_24kc_gcc-8.4.0_musl/lib/gcc/mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/8.4.0/../../../../mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_video
/home/test/openwrt/staging_dir/toolchain-mipsel_24kc_gcc-8.4.0_musl/lib/gcc/mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/8.4.0/../../../../mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_xobjdetect
/home/test/openwrt/staging_dir/toolchain-mipsel_24kc_gcc-8.4.0_musl/lib/gcc/mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/8.4.0/../../../../mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_objdetect
/home/test/openwrt/staging_dir/toolchain-mipsel_24kc_gcc-8.4.0_musl/lib/gcc/mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/8.4.0/../../../../mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_calib3d
/home/test/openwrt/staging_dir/toolchain-mipsel_24kc_gcc-8.4.0_musl/lib/gcc/mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/8.4.0/../../../../mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_imgcodecs
/home/test/openwrt/staging_dir/toolchain-mipsel_24kc_gcc-8.4.0_musl/lib/gcc/mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/8.4.0/../../../../mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_features2d
/home/test/openwrt/staging_dir/toolchain-mipsel_24kc_gcc-8.4.0_musl/lib/gcc/mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/8.4.0/../../../../mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_flann
/home/test/openwrt/staging_dir/toolchain-mipsel_24kc_gcc-8.4.0_musl/lib/gcc/mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/8.4.0/../../../../mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_xphoto
/home/test/openwrt/staging_dir/toolchain-mipsel_24kc_gcc-8.4.0_musl/lib/gcc/mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/8.4.0/../../../../mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_photo
/home/test/openwrt/staging_dir/toolchain-mipsel_24kc_gcc-8.4.0_musl/lib/gcc/mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/8.4.0/../../../../mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_imgproc
/home/test/openwrt/staging_dir/toolchain-mipsel_24kc_gcc-8.4.0_musl/lib/gcc/mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/8.4.0/../../../../mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_core
ind -lopencv_xphoto
/home/test/openwrt/staging_dir/toolchain-mipsel_24kc_gcc-8.4.0_musl/lib/gcc/mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/8.4.0/../../../../mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_photo
/home/test/openwrt/staging_dir/toolchain-mipsel_24kc_gcc-8.4.0_musl/lib/gcc/mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/8.4.0/../../../../mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_imgproc
/home/test/openwrt/staging_dir/toolchain-mipsel_24kc_gcc-8.4.0_musl/lib/gcc/mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/8.4.0/../../../../mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_core

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["opencv2: no such file or directory" while trying to build Darknet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64865462/opencv2-no-such-file-or-directory-while-trying-to-build-darknet)

Comment: Have opencv.pc file already, g++ compile is ok, run mipsel-openwrt-linux-g++  is error, Do want opencv.pc modify with openwrt ?

Comment: Yes, try it and make sure the paths are correct.